# Node isn't logging error messages to MongoDB as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, logging, winston

I'm trying to create an error message/log using "winston-mongodb" while sending it to my database. In my MongoDB Compass it created a log folder as expected, but there's no data in it.

Here's my code:

index.js

```
require("winston-mongodb");

winston.add(new winston.transports.MongoDB({ db: "mongodb://localhost/vidly_node_js" }));
```

genres.js

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
   throw new Error("Could not get the genres.");
   const genres = await Genre.find().sort("name");
   res.send(genres);
});
```

I'm supposed to be getting this:

[image]

But this is what I keep getting:

[image]

**What am I missing???**

Also **"throw new Error("Could not get the genres.")"** is making the code down below in my get function "unreachable". Maybe that's the reason? If so, what do I need todo to fix it? Because it’s giving me an error that says:

```
TypeError: common.clone is not a function
```

[image]

Comment: Please share version of `winston-mongodb` and `winston`  you are using.

Comment: For winston-mongodb I'm using 3.0.0 and for winston I'm using the latest version

Answer (score 2):

Upagrade `winston-mongodb` package to version 4+ to work with latest `winston`

https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-mongodb/issues/108

> Winston 3 and mongodb 3 support is now in the winston-mongodb 4.x branch.

winston-mongodb 3.0 is not compatible with latest winston

https://github.com/winstonjs/winston-mongodb/tree/v3.0.1

> Current version supports only mongodb driver version 2.x. If you want to use winston-mongodb with mongodb version 1.4.x use winston-mongodb <1.x.